# Why do I need to create a struct and then a pointer to it's address?

Tags: c, linux, memory

I'm working with `comedilib` in a C program and I'm trying to understand this line:

```
comedi_cmd c, *cmd = &c;
```

`comedi_cmd` is a struct which contains a bunch of integers and a pointer to a data array. The variable `c` is not used anywhere else. If I omit creating `c` and just do:

```
comedi_cmd *cmd;
```

...then I start getting segfaults.

Why can we not simply create the pointer to a `comedi_cmd` struct? Is this a way of allocating memory?

Is this some C magic that I'm unaware of?

For more context, the line in question from the `comedilib` examples is here:
https://github.com/Linux-Comedi/comedilib/blob/master/demo/tut3.c#L68

Comment: It's because it needs to pass it to functions that require a pointer. "*Why can we not simply create the pointer*". You certainly can which is in fact  what `cmd` is. But you still need to point it to something. If you mean something else then please show what code you had in mind.

Comment: `comedi_cmd *cmd;` That just creates an unintialised pointer. You need to point it to something before it can be used. Otherwise it has a garbage value in it and not a valid address of a struct as it needs to be.

Comment: I had thought that the fact I'm using the `comedi_cmd` type indicates that `cmd` should point to a memory address that represents the struct, but I can see that they don't follow up with a malloc or anything.

Perhaps an equivalent initialization would be:
`comedi_cmd *cmd = NULL; cmd = malloc(sizeof(comedi_cmd));`

Comment: Yes that is another way to do it. But if the struct does not need to be kept beyond the current function then using the local struct variable exactly as shown is much simpler and just as effective. In both cases `cmd` will end up pointing to a valid struct.

Comment: "*cmd should point to a memory address that represents the struct"*. Well it does. That's exactly what `cmd = &c` does. Why do you think it's not pointing to a struct after that?

Comment: Thanks, I think I just forgot (or took for granted) the importance of initialization of pointers.  I've typically used the `NULL` + `malloc` approach, so this implementation threw me. This resolves my question.

Comment: The other way would be to actually just have `comedi_cmd c` and work with `&c` in place of `cmd`.

Comment: *"The variable c is not used anywhere else."* It is used indirectly via `*cmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the line into two lines:

```
comedi_cmd c;
comedi_cmd *cmd = &c;
```

The first line has the effect of allocating enough memory on the stack to contain variable `c` of type `comedi_cmd`. That's where your bunch of integers and a pointer will be stored in memory.

The second line defines `cmd`, a pointer to `comedi_cmd`, and initializes it with the address of `c`, which is where the the bunch of integers and a pointer are stored in memory.

If you were to define `cmd` uninitialized:

```
comedi_cmd *cmd;
```

then it would have an undefined value (address). Dereferencing it would likely cause a `SIGSEGV`, as you observed. You must make sure that `cmd` points to valid memory, and `c` is the valid memory in this case.

Comment: Thanks, after reading the comments from @kaylum it became clear what I was missing. Coming from a background with higher level langs like Python I was taking the memory allocation for the reference `cmd` for granted. I've accepted this as I felt it gave the most clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is evident that you need to create an object of the structure type that contains "a bunch of integers and a pointer to a data array".

This object will be changed in some functions. To change exactly the object and not a copy of the object within functions you need to pass it to functions by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Dereferencing the pointer functions will have a direct access to the passed object.

You could write for example calling a function

```
some_function( &c );
```

However you can introduce an intermediate variable of a pointer type like

```
comedi_cmd *cmd = &c;
```

and use it in function calls instead of the expression `&c`.

```
some_function( cmd );
```